# jquery: add html after a group of divs

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:
...

```
<div id="d120" >content</div>
<div id="d123" >content</div>
<div id="d112" >content</div>
<div id="d145" >content</div>
<div id="d134" >content</div>
//Insert here hello world

<div id="bla" >asd</div>
<div id="footer" >asd</div>
```

anybody knows how to insert html after all the divs that have id like d+number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format doesn't have anything between those divs and `#bla` like your example, here's a safer approach using [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) (since `div[id^=d]` would match `<div id="doodlesticks">` as well).

```
$("#bla").before("<b>Hi There</b>");
```

**Update:** Since you said it's possible to give them a class, I'd do that, so give the content divs a `class="content"` and use this jQuery:

```
$(".content:last").after("<b>Hi There</b>");
```

Comment: no bla was just to show that there is something else in there, but i don't know what is going to be, although it's a good idea to

Comment: @Omu - possible to give those content divs a class?  Matching just on a starting `d` isn't all that safe, what else you have to work with?

Comment: @Omu - I'd give them a class then, and use `$(".MyClass:last").after(htmlStringHere);`, updated the answer to show this approach.

Answer (score 3):

This will safely test for elements whose id ends with a number, instead of any id that start with "d".

```
$('div[id]').filter(function() {
    return /\d+$/.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).last().after(...my html...);
```

Comment: +1: This looks to be more generic solution as per the html markup and requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div[id^=d]:last").after("some html");
```

or:

```
$("some html").insertAfter("div[id^=d]:last");
```

Comment: Do you really think this is a safe approach?

Comment: not really, there at least needs to be a couple more characters at the start of the IDs to eleminate the potential for a *natural* disaster (other divs with id starting with d). I reckon they should be assigned a common class instead.

Answer (score 0):

add another div with an id and then just change the html for that element $('#id').html('html');

unless that will break your page layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('div[id^="d"]:last').after('<div>Hello World</div>');
});
```

**Note:** As suggested by Nick Craver, this would match any div whose `id` starts with `d` but i think that's what you have to resort to as per your html markup.